# What make this code to be execute over and over

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS and currently studying for my MTA exam, so I am not an expert as you can see. 
I don't get where is the element that makes this code to be **execute over and over**.

When the document loads, `init()` is called, it gets the element that is going to be moved and then it calls `move_par()`

And here the function moves the element until it reaches 300. Why after this is executed it starts over again?

Can you help.?
Thanks

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Animation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function move_par() {
            current += 1;
            if (current > 300) {
                current = 0;
            }
            par.style.left = current;
            var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
            setTimeout(move_par, rate);
        }
        function init() {
            par = document.getElementById("ori");
            par.style.position = "absolute";
            current = 0;
            move_par();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <h1> animation with js</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="rate" type="number" value="18" min="1" max="100">
        </input>
    </form>
    <p id="ori"> Do you see me  moving?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `setTimeout(move_par, rate)`, `move_par()` is executed every `rate` milliseconds.

Comment: thanks Kyle ...according toW3school 
   set time out shoul be executed once.         
 "Definition and Usage”    The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. 
Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second. 
Tip: The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the setInterval() method. Tip: Use the clearTimeout() method to prevent the function to run." –
so why is repeating more than once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first animation is fired in the `init()` function where you call `move_par();` The second animation is fired because you call the function again from within a `setTimeout(move_par, rate);` wrapper.

Comment: War  Thanks  . But according to w3schools.com set time out shoul be executed once. 
"Definition and Usage”
 The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. 
Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second. 
Tip: The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the setInterval() method. Tip: Use the clearTimeout() method to prevent the function to run." – So shouldnt this be executen ONCE  and the if I want to be repeated usesetInterval?

Comment: @shark6552 That's correct. However, the callbunch function your using `move_par` contains the `setTimeout`. This causes the recursion effect that you're seeing. Each `setTimeout` executes only once. However, each time you're callback `move_par` is called after `rate` milliseconds, the function is executed and a ***new*** `setTimeout` is created creating a recursive endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

move_par ends up with the line setTimeout(move_par, rate); which schedule a new execution of the function, so it seems normal behavior. You need to return earlier from the function if you don't want to call it again.

Comment: Thanks JP yes I know is a normal behavior, I just dont know why or what and I want to learn what  was making this to repeat . But according to w3schools.com set time out shoul be executed once. "Definition and Usage
The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.

Tip: The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the setInterval() method.

Tip: Use the clearTimeout() method to prevent the function to run."

Comment: the function is setimeout not interval so why is repeating ?

Comment: you call setTimeout INSIDE move_par. So everytime move_par runs, it schedules itself once more, so it runs again, and calls setTimeout on itself again etc.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#rate").change(function() {
  value = $(this).val();
  $("#ori").css("margin-left",value+'px')
});
```

Then add margin-left: 0 to the #ori element and it should work.

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVNXMq)